# How do I tell xcode to include a specific block of code if it matches iOS 11?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if sections[section].items.count ==  0{
        return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
    }
    return tableView.sectionHeaderHeight
}
```

I only want this code to appear if it's iOS 11.  If user is on iOS 10, I don't want to implement this delegate in any way.

Answer (score 2):

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    // set delegate here
} else {
    // do nothing
}
```